# How to click on an WPFObject("Image") which is visible only on hovering over it?

Tags: testcomplete

There is a close button(WPFObject("Image") in my WPF application which is visible only if i hover over it .I need to click on it.But when i specify it's reference , TestComplete is not able to find it as its not visible.

Is there anyway to click on it without specifying the co-ordinates (as that's not 100% reliable) ?
I am using TC9 and Jscript.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HoverMouse method to activate the button and click it after this. Here is how your code can look:

```
var panel = //obtain the parent object of the button
// Hover the mouse over the center of the button
panel.HoverMouse(button.Bounds.Left + button.Bounds.Width/2,
                     button.Bounds.Top + button.Bounds.Height/2)
var button = // obtain the button object
// Wait a bit if needed
var button.WaitProperty("VisibleOnScreen", true, 2000)
// Click the button
button.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible there is an image "underneath" or "behind" the close button that is displayed that you can click on?  How would a human user do it?  I've seen this kind of thing before, and sometimes what you want to do is easier if you think about it a round-about way.